# Ruby on Rails does not generate foreign key from association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I have two set up two database tables called 'points' and 'activities'. I want to give the table 'points' a foreign key 'activity_id' by setting up the associations as follows:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :points, dependent: :destroy
   ...
end
```

and

```
class Point < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :activity

end
```

In addition, I have the following migrations file for creating the points table:

```
class CreatePoints < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :points do |t|

      t.integer :activity_id
      t.timestamps null: false
      t.boolean :activities_completed, array: true, default: []
      t.integer :point_value
      t.float :time_left    


    end
  end
end
```

However, when I run

```
rake db:reset
rake db:migrate
rake db:seed
```

and then check the the table points by

```
rails c
Point.column_names
```

then the foreign key is missing:

```
irb(main):001:0> Point.column_names
=> ["id", "created_at", "updated_at", "activities_completed", "point_value", "time_left"]
```

What am I doing wrong? What can I do to make the foreign key activity_id a column of the points table?

I am new to Ruby and Rails. My Rails version is 4.24. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your create table migration should have a "t.belongs_to :activity, index: true" instead of creating the field activity_id with type integer.

Answer (score 0):

You should have done something like this to add activity_id to your points table.

```
t.references :activity, index: true, foreign_key: true
#this would have created activity_id column in points
```

Since now, you have already created your migrations and ran `rake db:migrate`, learn to remove a column from a table. You need to write migrations to remove `activity_id` from your points table and add it again.

```
rails generate migration RemoveActivityIdFromPoints activity_id:integer
rails g migration AddActivityRefToPoints activity:references
```

These two should create proper migrations for you. Check your migrations folder for confirmation that everything went well, and run `rake db:migrate` and test again.

Follow this link to learn more about it. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that there was a more fundamental problem. The migration script was not being executed during rake db:migrate. Therefore the changes I had made to the migration were ineffective. I therefore had to use

```
rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=20160605234351
```

When I ran this command, then the foreign key appeared.